# How to setup a S3 backed Media server with basic auth / password protection

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress, apache2, amazon-s3, media-server

**Requirement**

- Serve audios and videos stored in a S3 bucket
- Selectively protect folders with basic auth (username password);
- Low latency as much as possible but not necessary
- Cost is also a factor but open to ideas
- Way for media team to Upload the new content. (For s3 they need to make each file public manually)
- We are a very small team with limited resources

**Current Setup**

- Data stored in a s3 bucket
- A website running inside an EC2 instance
- Apache2 server

**Our considerations**

- Reverse proxy s3 urls at apache level and configure basic auth at the apache level. BUT <s>it requires keeping all the bucket objects public</s> and then applying bucket policies which is getting out of hands!
- Block S3 public access completely and then use AWS PHP SDK to serve the cone tent. Then let media team upload new content from the AWS console. With this option not sure how latency will be impacted.

We are sure there will be some good solutions available for the similar requirements please point us to a viable solution Thanks a lot.

Edit: For now we have kept bucket private with blocking all the public access. then added bucket policy to allow public access only to our EC2 instance and this way we have achieved what we wanted. But still open for a complete low latency viable solution which we can move towards.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than an EC2 you probably want to look at serving a static website either via S3 or CloudFront. CloudFront would also let you make the bucket private. If you need a dynamic site, host the APIs only on the EC2 (or Lambda & API Gateway) and reach them from the S3 hosted site.

In any case - CloudFront will let you serve the content from the bucket whilst keeping the bucket private, and provide good latency etc.

Comment: We also need password protection or any other way to protect the content. 
For the same reason we haven't tried CloudFront which might have improved our latency.
Thanks for your response.